# Duda con Jquery y Ajax al enviar parámetros

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, mysqli

Estoy intentando realizar una función de jquery de la siguiente forma:

```
  $('#indiceOD').on('change', function(){
var familia = $('#familiaOD').val()
var id_indice = $('#indiceOD').val()
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'php/cargar_tratamientos.php',
  data: {'id': id_indice, 'id_familia' : familia}
})
.done(function(listas_rep){
  $('#TratamientoOD').html(listas_rep)
})
.fail(function(){
  alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los materiales')
})
```

})

El caso, es que esto es un combo de muchos niveles de selects, en este me gustaría poder pasarle dos valores al archivo "cargar_tratamientos.php"

Con el objetivo: de que si la "Familia tiene ID1, devuelva una consulta, y si tiene otra ID, que mandre la segunda consulta, para así en el select, rellanarlo de una forma u de otra.

Gracias a todos, CREO que me he explicado bien.

Comment: Amigo estas seguro de que si se pasan los valores que pones cómo parámetros ya que estoy viendo que el id e id_familia están en comillas simples, por ende deberían estar sin comillas y en tu PHP recibirlos con el GET en mi caso si me funciona enviar por POST y recibirlos por GET.

Comment: ¿Y el problema cuál es? ¿Cuál es el código PHP que recibe los datos en el servidor y hace la consulta según   los datos que se envían desde Ajax?

Comment: He solucionado este problema, re-progamando desde arriba, añadiendo algunas condiciones de "estructura" vertical, voy jugando con los IF, y he conseguido solucionar este ejemplo y varios más!, Gracias de todos modos por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías enviar el código HTML?
Creo que el problema es que sólo estás afectando a un solo elemento select en la línea:

```
  $('#indiceOD').on('change', function(){
```

Comment: He solucionado este problema, re-progamando desde arriba, añadiendo algunas condiciones de "estructura" vertical, voy jugando con los IF, y he conseguido solucionar este ejemplo y varios más!, Gracias de todos modos por la ayuda!